# Ruby: syntax for string interpolation and commenting

Tags: ruby, comments, string-interpolation

*There are a lot of similar questions to this one but i think none really had the answer i was in need of.*

From what i perceived, anything that has a `#` preceding it becomes a comment, as in:

```
puts "not a comment"
# puts "in a comment"
```

but when it come to string interpolation, you can say:

```
puts "time is #{Time.now}"
```

and the `#` at `#{Time.now}` doesn't start commenting whatever is written after it.

How is it so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The # sign in this case is encased in quotation marks, and is parsed as part of the string, not as a comment.

Comment: is there a way that i could add comments inside a string, such that it does not get parsed?

Comment: I don't think adding comments within a string is a 'best practice'.  Why are you wanting to do this?

Comment: its more curiosity i guess, guess then its not technically possible?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, what @Osama said. But also, if you put a comment inside the chunk of Ruby code, it won't comment out the rest of the entire line. So,

```
puts "'#{'oof'#.reverse},' he said."
```

wil print "'oof,' he said", while

```
puts "'#{'oof'.reverse},' he said."
```

results in "'foo,' he said".